# $f:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ be a monotone, bijective map, $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[image]

I am sure that $f$ must be continuous.My intuition says $f^{-1}$ need not be continuous but I have no counter example. $2,3,4$ are surely false. Could any one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ be a monotone bijective function then $f^{-1}$ is also monotone bijection, so is continuous.